# MAC spoofing on a Bluetooth LE Device (Bluetooth Low Energy security)

Tags: security, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, spoofing, mac-spoofing

I am concerned with the MAC spoofing on a Bluetooth LE Device.
Is it possible during only the bonding or would be possible in any step of the connection (pairing, bonding, scan, data exchange, etc...)

Comment: What is your concern? If you need security in your connection then you need to bond and exchange keys with your device. The initial bonding could be with a spoofed device, which is why there is typically an out of band token such as pairing pin displayed on one device

Comment: Since not all the devices in the market supports full OOB bonding, I will not use it, but i want to prevent Man-in-the-middle attack

Comment: If you use 'just works' pairing then you can't prevent MITM - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Pairing_and_bonding

Comment: I will configure filtering: the LL controller maintains a “white list” of allowed devices and will ignore all requests for data exchange or advertising information from others

Comment: But the address can be spoofed as you say....

Comment: ok, so white list at the end is no so secure ?

Comment: Well, the address is sent from the device "in the clear", so an attacker can intercept that and spoof the device's address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is achievable.

Mike Ryan from iSEC Partners used specific hardware to achieve injection, in his article *[Bluetooth: with low energy comes low security](https://lacklustre.net/bluetooth/Ryan_Bluetooth_Low_Energy_USENIX_WOOT.pdf)*

> From Ubertooth we send undirected advertising messages broadcasting
>   the existence of a device with a user-specified MAC address.

And here is the [presentation at Usenix WOOT'13 conference](https://www.usenix.org/conference/woot13/workshop-program/presentation/Ryan).